# How to write once the common code in build.gradle files in a multi module android project

Tags: build.gradle

I am just recently approaching modularization with the version catalog and I have noticed that the same attributes are always present in each module in defaultConfing:

minSdk

targetSdk and in the android block compileSdk.

is it possible to write these attributes once and for all and have them inherited by each build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I encountered this problem,
Firstly, define ext in root-level

```
ext {
    configuration = [
            applicationId    : "com.example.app",
            compileSdkVersion: 34,
            targetSdkVersion : 34,
            minSdkVersion    : 27
    ]
}
```

Then in you Gradle module-level, you can access the configurations:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion configuration.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion configuration.targetSdkVersion
    }
}
```